# What are the reasons you would not migrate a SQL Server Instance to SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have some servers and some databases on SQL Azure and as much as I like this idea, I would like to know some good reasons to migrate a SQL Server instance to the cloud and what reasons would be a bad idea. The pros obviously are backups, security, automatic patches...

But one con, for example, is that it doesn't have SQL Agent to schedule jobs. I found a lot of posts to bypass this but it seems all of them are just "try this try that".

I would like to know what good reasons would be to NOT migrate my servers to the cloud.

Comment: Security a "pro"?  https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2020/01/30/severe-perfect-100-microsoft-flaw-confirmed-this-is-a-cloud-security-nightmare/#1a85bdd5b4a4

Comment: wow...thats why the question. I would love to know the point of view of some people around here. I don't want my question to be closed but I don't know another way to ask something like this,.

Comment: Yes, this type of "opinion-based" question is useful, but the problem is it becomes outdated.  Also see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/how-fast-can-a-21468-mo-azure-sql-db-load-data/.  My own opinion is that if it's working fine, don't touch it.  Just creating work, and if you already own the hardware, you'll then have a bunch of idle hardware.  Keep your money, and get your money out of your existing hardware.  If there was a really great reason to migrate, you wouldn't be asking this question!  For new deployments, makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Thanks tony I use to think like you, but I'm not good expressing myself.

Answer (score 1):

> But one con, for example, is that it doesn't have SQL Agent to schedule jobs.

You will find that this already is of very limited use outside of backups. Most applications that I know of have schedulers on the application layer that control everything and then call i.e. into a SP to do a reorganization. The scheduler is only useful for pure DB things - backups, performance reporting etc - for which Azure has other solutions.

Real reasons are:

- Ability to move to on premise and/or use on premise for development. Azure server side is still different. At minimum you get latency - which can be brutal. At worst your local SQL Server has a slightly different feature set and that bites you.
- Database size limitations.
- Price. Depending on use, copies of databases for development may be free on your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to look at this from the opposite perspective. If I am looking into potentially reducing my overall costs then is there a reason why I CANNOT move to the cloud.

In Azure there are also multiple options that can be considered to ensure you have something which is fit for purpose. There is the Single Database option, Elastic Pools to get better resource utilisation from a number of databases, Managed Instances and also the option to simply lift an shift onto an Azure VM. Each has their own advantages and disadvantages which should be considered.

The issues you mention such as no SQL Agent are also addressed. For Single and Elastic Pools there is the Elastic Job Agent and Managed Instance does include SQL Agent.

Once you have considered the options and identified the one that covers the functionality you need, then you can dive in to pricing to identify if it also makes commercial sense to make the move. Ensure that you do consider all the running costs, not just how much did my server and disks cost, when looking at this.

Comment: And technical debt as well.  We are in a higher tier than we would necessarily otherwise be in precisely because we carried the technical debt with us.  On the other hand, now that I have a concrete, ongoing monthly $$ associated with that debt, we finally have authorization to pay it off...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking there are not many good reason to not move into Azure. You have various options and this will be the  future unless you have restrictions from your client to keep data OFF cloud or in their DC.

Azure SQL Managed Instance for example is the closest to your On-Premises SQL Server and has all the capabilities  (Agent service included).

Also it is not just moving the database, the applications and databases have to moved together to your selected cloud option (AWS or Azure). All in all it is a collective decision to move or NOT to move to cloud as a whole. You shouldn't just move the database to cloud while keep the app on-prem as this might affect the performance due to latency.

For me the only reason for NOT moving into cloud would be the restrictions due to confidentiality of your data.

Comment: Given the compliance options available in Azure, any concerns about security just because you are in the cloud are outdated.  You are far more likely to suffer a breach because it wasn't configured properly.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/trusted-cloud/

Comment: Yep agreed. I was talking about clients where the data is confidential enough (example : A nuclear power project). It is tough to convince them where the data is this confidential.

Comment: Ah, yes I was thinking more of commercial security concerns and not government "top secret".  That's a whole different ball of wax.